# How to encrypt PCM data before it is AMRNB encoded

Tags: security, encryption

I'm trying to implement security voice call on the phone. The processing steps should be as following.

Uplink: User -> PCM data(16bit, 8KHz) -> Encryption -> AMRNB encoding -> Network
Downlink: Network -> AMRNB decoding -> Decryption -> PCM data -> User

The only part on which I can do encryption/decryption is PCM data in this case. This is the restriction of the whole phone project.

Following things I have tried,

1. Reverse the position of PCM data in frequency domain before uplink, as following,
   PCM -> FFT -> Reverse frequency data based on some rule -> IFFT.
   With this method, the PCM data is scrambled. But we can't say it's safe enough for a security call.
2. I studied some encryption algorithm, like AES, DES, RSA and etc. But in all of them, multi bytes(at least 8) need to be taken as input of encryption.(Please correct me if I'm wrong here) But I think that with this kind of encryption, it couldn't be decrypted back after AMRNB encoding and decoding.

So my question is whether there is encryption algorithm which can take 16bit(one frame of PCM data in this cast) data as its plaintext input to satisfy this case.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't encrypt each 16 bit frame individually even if you could; an attacker can easily brute-force the 2^16 (65536) possibilities. Instead combine 4 frames and encrypt them together. If you encrypt the data and then encode it in AMRNB, then it will not compress the encrypted voice well; AMRNB is designed for voice, not encrypted voice.

Comment: Yes, encryption of 16bit frame is not safe at all. For the AMRNB things, if encrypt 4 frame together, after AMRNB encoding and decoding, the data couldn't be decrypted back. But if one frame encryption, i still can decrypt them (or most of them)back after encoding/decoding. Am I right?